# How to parse to get the data in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have lot of confused for the parsing year,month,day,hour.How to show for he given data.

```
 var parseDate =d3.time.format("%d %b").parse;
 var data=[{"key":[2000,0,1,0],"value":1000},{"key":[2000,1,1,1]},"value":2000},{"key":[2000,2,2,2]},"value":3000},{"key":[2000,4,4,4]},"value":5000}]
i wrote the code is given below
var data1 = data.map(function (d,i){return {key:parseDate((d.key[1])+" "+d.key[0]),value:+d.value}});
console.log(data1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Time formatting is described here:
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting

Assuming your key array is [year,month,day,hour(24hours)] you need to write:

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y.%m.%d.%H").parse;
...
var data1 = data.map(function (d,i){
return {key:parseDate(
(d.key[0]+"."+d.key[1]+"."d.key[2])+"."+d.key[3])
,value:+d.value}
});
```

Based on the links below, I suspect a) you are posting your questions under different usernames and b) you don't accept answers. See

[How to get the data from given array of objects in d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28115582/how-to-get-the-data-from-given-array-of-objects-in-d3-js/28119687#28119687)

[I unable show the x-axis year and month using d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28110490/i-unable-show-the-x-axis-year-and-month-using-d3-js/28120051#28120051)